# Anybody written a tool for static analysis of an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, static-analysis

Has anyone written a tool to do static analysis of an ASP.NET MVC application?

Disclaimer: I'm not sure what I want really is [static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis) - it just was the closest term I could come up with.

What I'd like is to get a tabulated list of all my controllers, my actions, show whether they respond to GET or POST, what their cache settings are etc.

I'm sure you could keep going and goin with this - and go on to more advanced issues like whether or not every action is actually accessible by a route.

If nobody has done this - is it something that people think would be useful ? What else ought it to do?

Comment: Technically speaking that is static analysis, but most people think of other things when they hear that word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test routes you can use [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib). It contains many various cool features and route debugging handler is one of them. And at the moment this is all what I saw. It will be rather hard to create a good tool to show all information that you described because architecture of asp.net mvc is very flexible and architecture of projects can be very different. But if you use NHibernate in your projects you should have a look at [NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/).